# Ts objects in R

Tags: r, date, time, statistics, time-series

I am trying to convert monthly streamflow data at several stations to time series objects in R using the function ts with the following code:

```
ts_MonthlyMean <- lapply(df_MonthyMean, function(x){ts(x$MonthlyMeanStreamflow,
                                                              frequency=12,
                                                              start=c(x[1,1],x[1,2]), 
                                                              end=c(tail(x$year,1),tail(x$month,1)))})
```

with input, df_MonthlyMean that it is a list of 31 data frames. This is the structure of one of them:

```
> str(df_MonthyMean[[1]])
'data.frame':   809 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ year                 : int  1953 1953 1953 1953 1953 1953 1953 1954 1954 1954 ...
 $ month                : int  6 7 8 9 10 11 12 1 2 3 ...
 $ MonthlyMeanStreamflow: num  25.1 32.2 26.2 11.6 13.6 ...

> dput(round(df_MonthyMean[[1]],1))
structure(list(year = c(1953, 1953, 1953, 1953, 1953, 1953, 1953, 
1954, 1954, 1954, 1954, 1954, 1954, 1954, 1954, 1954, 1954, 1954, 
1954, 1955, 1955, 1955, 1955, 1955, 1955, 1955, 1955, 1955, 1955, 
1955, 1955, 1956, 1956, 1956, 1956, 1956, 1956, 1956, 1956, 1956, 
1956, 1956, 1956, 1957, 1957, 1957, 1957, 1957, 1957, 1957, 1957, 
1957, 1957, 1957, 1957, 1958, 1958, 1958, 1958, 1958, 1958, 1958, 
1958, 1958, 1958, 1958, 1958, 1959, 1959, 1959, 1959, 1959, 1959, 
1959, 1959, 1959, 1959, 1959, 1959, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 
1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1961, 1961, 1961, 1961, 
1961, 1961, 1961, 1961, 1961, 1961, 1961, 1961, 1962, 1962, 1962, 
1962, 1962, 1962, 1962, 1962, 1962, 1962, 1962, 1962, 1963, 1963, 
1963, 1963, 1963, 1963, 1963, 1963, 1963, 1963, 1963, 1963, 1964, 
1964, 1964, 1964, 1964, 1964, 1964, 1964, 1964, 1964, 1964, 1964, 
1965, 1965, 1965, 1965, 1965, 1965, 1965, 1965, 1965, 1965, 1965, 
1965, 1966, 1966, 1966, 1966, 1966, 1966, 1966, 1966, 1966, 1966, 
1966, 1966, 1967, 1967, 1967, 1967, 1967, 1967, 1967, 1967, 1967, 
1967, 1967, 1967, 1968, 1968, 1968, 1968, 1968, 1968, 1968, 1968, 
1968, 1968, 1968, 1968, 1969, 1969, 1969, 1969, 1969, 1969, 1969, 
1969, 1969, 1969, 1969, 1969, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 
1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1971, 1971, 1971, 1971, 1971, 
1971, 1971, 1971, 1971, 1971, 1971, 1971, 1972, 1972, 1972, 1972, 
1972, 1972, 1972, 1972, 1972, 1972, 1972, 1972, 1973, 1973, 1973, 
1973, 1973, 1973, 1973, 1973, 1973, 1973, 1973, 1973, 1974, 1974, 
1974, 1974, 1974, 1974, 1974, 1974, 1974, 1974, 1974, 1974, 1975, 
1975, 1975, 1975, 1975, 1975, 1975, 1975, 1975, 1975, 1975, 1975, 
1976, 1976, 1976, 1976, 1976, 1976, 1976, 1976, 1976, 1976, 1976, 
1976, 1977, 1977, 1977, 1977, 1977, 1977, 1977, 1977, 1977, 1977, 
1977, 1977, 1978, 1978, 1978, 1978, 1978, 1978, 1978, 1978, 1978, 
1978, 1978, 1978, 1979, 1979, 1979, 1979, 1979, 1979, 1979, 1979, 
1979, 1979, 1979, 1979, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 
1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 
1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1982, 1982, 1982, 1982, 1982, 
1982, 1982, 1982, 1982, 1982, 1982, 1982, 1983, 1983, 1983, 1983, 
1983, 1983, 1983, 1983, 1983, 1983, 1983, 1983, 1984, 1984, 1984, 
1984, 1984, 1984, 1984, 1984, 1984, 1984, 1984, 1984, 1985, 1985, 
1985, 1985, 1985, 1985, 1985, 1985, 1985, 1985, 1985, 1985, 1986, 
1986, 1986, 1986, 1986, 1986, 1986, 1986, 1986, 1986, 1986, 1986, 
1987, 1987, 1987, 1987, 1987, 1987, 1987, 1987, 1987, 1987, 1987, 
1987, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 
1988, 1988, 1989, 1989, 1989, 1989, 1989, 1989, 1989, 1989, 1989, 
1989, 1989, 1989, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 
1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 
1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 
1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1993, 
1993, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 
1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1995, 1995, 1995, 
1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1996, 1996, 
1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1997, 
1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 
1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 
1998, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 
1999, 1999, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 
2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 
2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 
2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 
2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2006, 2006, 2006, 
2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2007, 2007, 
2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2008, 
2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 
2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 
2009, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 
2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 
2011, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 
2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020), 
    month = c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
    9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 
    2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
    8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
    7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
    7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
    7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
    7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
    7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
    7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
    7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
    7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
    7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
    7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
    7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
    7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
    7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
    7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
    7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
    7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
    7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
    7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
    7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
    7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
    7, 8, 9, 10), MonthlyMeanStreamflow = c(25.1, 32.2, 26.2, 
    11.6, 13.6, 22.7, 20, 26.5, 38.6, 322.6, 279.7, 68.3, 14.7, 
    36.5, 87.7, 34.7, 22.5, 29.5, 28.5, 36.6, 46, 67.9, 49.5, 
    25.1, 14.4, 46, 342.9, 55.8, 26.5, 30.5, 42.9, 42, 80.5, 
    273.4, 189, 65.1, 17.2, 20.9, 27.4, 9.4, 15.1, 29.1, 28.4, 
    77.9, 223.1, 257.8, 239.3, 148.1, 56.9, 44, 376.2, 103.7, 
    61.1, 124.1, 75.5, 47.9, 141.4, 760.8, 1872.3, 649.4, 85.1, 
    31.6, 53.9, 154, 206.5, 60.2, 51.2, 40.5, 48.5, 66.6, 66.5, 
    29.7, 19.2, 33.2, 251.5, 60.5, 48.9, 163.5, 109, 205.5, 182.2, 
    1000.3, 506.9, 131.3, 42.7, 16.5, 20.4, 21.6, 41.8, 36.4, 
    35.6, 37.7, 46.7, 154.9, 197.2, 40.5, 23.5, 23.3, 32.4, 36.1, 
    37.9, 124.9, 182.1, 172.7, 654.5, 427.5, 1793.3, 295.2, 56.3, 
    34.2, 18.2, 41.7, 59.5, 54.4, 46, 50.1, 296.9, 321.1, 289.2, 
    69.2, 28.8, 32.1, 143.2, 384.6, 165.1, 128, 60.4, 36.6, 36.6, 
    90.6, 407.2, 111.3, 37.5, 48.5, 117.9, 296.8, 92.6, 50.1, 
    57.8, 322.2, 344, 549.7, 1282.8, 380.5, 68.1, 122.4, 139.9, 
    47.2, 34.4, 96.9, 472.7, 391.7, 167.2, 1383.9, 1208.9, 209.6, 
    39.7, 45.4, 90.8, 87.1, 51.6, 27.3, 45.6, 38.1, 46.6, 70.1, 
    62, 25.4, 22.3, 84.2, 378, 203.1, 52.5, 49.1, 61.1, 132.4, 
    537.7, 798.6, 1290.8, 473.8, 77.9, 41.9, 128.3, 36.9, 25.8, 
    39.2, 33.1, 153.5, 127.2, 325, 876.8, 222.7, 46.2, 27.7, 
    64.4, 134.7, 37.1, 55.7, 54.5, 50.3, 52.7, 219.4, 315.2, 
    128.7, 25.3, 24.8, 36.6, 85, 58.5, 26.5, 28.1, 44, 56.5, 
    78.7, 45.6, 23.1, 15.6, 28.8, 122, 86.4, 564.2, 200.7, 203.1, 
    151.8, 75.4, 158.5, 43.7, 24.8, 32.6, 24.5, 25.7, 65.2, 1210.7, 
    299.5, 174.6, 222.9, 276.7, 674.2, 2058.2, 1933, 244.3, 102.8, 
    54.8, 20.7, 22.3, 38, 36.9, 41.5, 34.7, 131.9, 110, 30, 9.8, 
    22.3, 75.5, 35, 95.4, 143.6, 48.5, 52.2, 87.2, 819.2, 1052.4, 
    518.3, 72.7, 47.8, 24.3, 120.6, 23.2, 25.1, 27.7, 32.2, 169.4, 
    232.8, 507.4, 214.1, 31.4, 37.3, 39.1, 24.2, 18.8, 24.7, 
    29.9, 32.7, 40.8, 64, 150.1, 50.4, 18, 42.7, 80.6, 48.2, 
    34.3, 33.4, 31.4, 40.5, 176.5, 1623.7, 1001.5, 222.7, 35.1, 
    27, 42.5, 23.7, 26.4, 282.7, 915.1, 391.6, 525.6, 1020.9, 
    2252.7, 800.2, 239.3, 57.4, 62, 21.5, 23, 32, 24.5, 92.9, 
    1036, 812, 1644.8, 890.7, 136.9, 61.8, 79.4, 76.2, 27.2, 
    40.7, 40.4, 28.3, 40.2, 194.2, 447.2, 120.8, 36.5, 51.8, 
    77.1, 61.5, 69.6, 38.3, 43.2, 57.2, 195.2, 664.1, 759, 337.8, 
    60.5, 30.7, 100.3, 75.1, 18.8, 48.7, 195.2, 173, 374.9, 1102.8, 
    1707.8, 1262, 230.1, 55.4, 97.4, 171.7, 851.3, 96.1, 196.7, 
    256.2, 171.8, 322.4, 260.1, 107.5, 22.6, 25.3, 68, 80.8, 
    268.8, 107, 602.6, 503.5, 611, 1863.1, 1336.3, 552.2, 108.8, 
    61.2, 123.4, 75.6, 100.6, 73.2, 82.7, 50.5, 329.9, 759.4, 
    538.3, 82, 39.3, 54.4, 47.5, 48.8, 76.9, 368, 227.4, 96.8, 
    232.2, 741.5, 1341.7, 411.7, 69.9, 39.7, 76.4, 39.4, 39.9, 
    97.4, 37, 35.1, 331.1, 457.2, 701.1, 328.1, 60.1, 54.6, 311.3, 
    366.2, 60.9, 51, 47.3, 71.3, 96.9, 389.8, 126.3, 42.7, 21.6, 
    14.1, 48.7, 29.5, 33.1, 32.2, 35.4, 45.8, 49.9, 108.4, 84.1, 
    44, 23.8, 49.8, 60.7, 49.8, 61.7, 59.2, 201.1, 308.5, 286, 
    1004.2, 1432.8, 394, 75.8, 50.5, 82.2, 131.3, 36.9, 56.7, 
    130.3, 135.2, 400.3, 864.7, 1120.7, 406.4, 226.6, 57.8, 202.7, 
    79.7, 46.2, 52.8, 240, 1570.8, 984.8, 1577, 1926.7, 687.2, 
    157.3, 62.2, 61.7, 61, 45.9, 49.1, 50.1, 41.5, 57.7, 458.3, 
    242.7, 79.1, 27.3, 17.2, 40.9, 182.6, 50.7, 505.3, 346.1, 
    249, 986.1, 1164.9, 429.3, 227.9, 69, 30.1, 54.9, 54.2, 30.4, 
    33.1, 23.8, 23, 39.5, 30.1, 32, 22.5, 25.2, 44.6, 66.8, 85.8, 
    58.5, 101, 79.2, 108.1, 194.7, 677.3, 342.1, 109.5, 34.7, 
    29.8, 39.7, 42.7, 32.1, 36.3, 37.7, 54.7, 124.5, 802, 1032.1, 
    465.5, 66.5, 50.6, 38.2, 31.2, 40, 37.1, 43, 38.6, 39.3, 
    31.2, 91.1, 33.8, 30.9, 67.3, 509, 120.3, 41.3, 38.2, 40.4, 
    40.1, 35.2, 44.9, 43.5, 31.2, 34.9, 34.2, 44.4, 27.5, 219, 
    332.3, 100.6, 52.6, 115.6, 426.8, 658.7, 152.7, 32, 33.4, 
    69.5, 35.3, 29.7, 32.3, 38.3, 36.2, 35.1, 35.2, 27, 23.1, 
    21.3, 50.8, 52.6, 74.4, 28.6, 47.4, 40.3, 61.3, 166, 629.8, 
    413.9, 102.5, 31.1, 29.2, 44.4, 121.1, 30.4, 67.4, 41, 42.5, 
    60.7, 564.9, 375.6, 65.6, 25, 37.7, 30.7, 29.7, 30, 47.2, 
    127.6, 358.6, 1124.4, 591.4, 766, 229.9, 50.9, 29.3, 53, 
    38.9, 30.3, 34, 32.7, 30.9, 30.4, 41.3, 53.1, 24.6, 24.9, 
    44.5, 599.1, 149.7, 79.6, 43.5, 36.4, 41, 95.2, 321.3, 145.9, 
    53.8, 32.4, 32.7, 203.4, 70.9, 54.2, 48.1, 152.8, 393.6, 
    600.7, 991.5, 532, 156.2, 50.5, 67.8, 138.4, 296.8, 97.1, 
    39.7, 46.1, 169.8, 235.3, 697.6, 256.7, 103.5, 42.3, 36.5, 
    30.6, 34.4, 32.6, 35.7, 38, 128.3, 164.4, 661.3, 1280.2, 
    390.9, 52.6, 63.8, 129.6, 44.9, 29.3, 29, 36, 35.8, 35.4, 
    63.9, 45.2, 25.3, 26.5, 64.9, 163, 96, 39.7, 27.8, 36.3, 
    64.1, 108.8, 335, 153.5, 33.6, 25.2, 33.1, 63.2, 52.7, 23.7, 
    27.9, 31.5, 86.1, 153.4, 481, 174.5, 48.6, 25.7, 203.1, 193.5, 
    578.7, 88.5, 55.3, 67.8, 42.6, 44, 115.3, 41.8, 26.5, 23.6, 
    47, 194.9, 136.4, 131.5, 49.1, 66, 99.4, 327.8, 203, 72.3, 
    43.1, 28.1, 178.9, 145.1, 168.8, 149.3, 374.5, 126.5, 88.4, 
    557.6, 281, 85.1, 41.8, 31.4, 32.9, 44.5, 26.2, 36.6, 48.3, 
    328.5, 527.2, 934.2, 684.3, 205.6, 63.3, 27.4, 66.8, 188.7, 
    30.4, 31.4, 22.3, 24.4, 26.9, 32.5, 32.9, 23.5, 24.7, 19.5, 
    29.9, 42.5, 43.9, 61.1, 33.4, 29, 75.5, 525.9, 1537.6, 611.8, 
    154, 46.4, 28.4, 41, 35.9, 31.6, 40.4, 217.2, 152.1, 393.1, 
    1191.2, 383.4, 78.7, 29.1, 33.9, 29.9, 24.1, 25.3)), row.names = c(NA, 
-809L), class = "data.frame")
```

The code seems to work properly, producing the following result:

```
> round(ts_MonthlyMean[[1]],1)
        Jan    Feb    Mar    Apr    May    Jun    Jul    Aug    Sep    Oct    Nov    Dec
1953                                      25.1   32.2   26.2   11.6   13.6   22.7   20.0
1954   26.5   38.6  322.6  279.7   68.3   14.7   36.5   87.7   34.7   22.5   29.5   28.5
1955   36.6   46.0   67.9   49.5   25.1   14.4   46.0  342.9   55.8   26.5   30.5   42.9
1956   42.0   80.5  273.4  189.0   65.1   17.2   20.9   27.4    9.4   15.1   29.1   28.4
1957   77.9  223.1  257.8  239.3  148.1   56.9   44.0  376.2  103.7   61.1  124.1   75.5
1958   47.9  141.4  760.8 1872.3  649.4   85.1   31.6   53.9  154.0  206.5   60.2   51.2
1959   40.5   48.5   66.6   66.5   29.7   19.2   33.2  251.5   60.5   48.9  163.5  109.0
1960  205.5  182.2 1000.3  506.9  131.3   42.7   16.5   20.4   21.6   41.8   36.4   35.6
1961   37.7   46.7  154.9  197.2   40.5   23.5   23.3   32.4   36.1   37.9  124.9  182.1
1962  172.7  654.5  427.5 1793.3  295.2   56.3   34.2   18.2   41.7   59.5   54.4   46.0
1963   50.1  296.9  321.1  289.2   69.2   28.8   32.1  143.2  384.6  165.1  128.0   60.4
1964   36.6   36.6   90.6  407.2  111.3   37.5   48.5  117.9  296.8   92.6   50.1   57.8
1965  322.2  344.0  549.7 1282.8  380.5   68.1  122.4  139.9   47.2   34.4   96.9  472.7
1966  391.7  167.2 1383.9 1208.9  209.6   39.7   45.4   90.8   87.1   51.6   27.3   45.6
1967   38.1   46.6   70.1   62.0   25.4   22.3   84.2  378.0  203.1   52.5   49.1   61.1
1968  132.4  537.7  798.6 1290.8  473.8   77.9   41.9  128.3   36.9   25.8   39.2   33.1
1969  153.5  127.2  325.0  876.8  222.7   46.2   27.7   64.4  134.7   37.1   55.7   54.5
1970   50.3   52.7  219.4  315.2  128.7   25.3   24.8   36.6   85.0   58.5   26.5   28.1
1971   44.0   56.5   78.7   45.6   23.1   15.6   28.8  122.0   86.4  564.2  200.7  203.1
1972  151.8   75.4  158.5   43.7   24.8   32.6   24.5   25.7   65.2 1210.7  299.5  174.6
1973  222.9  276.7  674.2 2058.2 1933.0  244.3  102.8   54.8   20.7   22.3   38.0   36.9
1974   41.5   34.7  131.9  110.0   30.0    9.8   22.3   75.5   35.0   95.4  143.6   48.5
1975   52.2   87.2  819.2 1052.4  518.3   72.7   47.8   24.3  120.6   23.2   25.1   27.7
1976   32.2  169.4  232.8  507.4  214.1   31.4   37.3   39.1   24.2   18.8   24.7   29.9
1977   32.7   40.8   64.0  150.1   50.4   18.0   42.7   80.6   48.2   34.3   33.4   31.4
1978   40.5  176.5 1623.7 1001.5  222.7   35.1   27.0   42.5   23.7   26.4  282.7  915.1
1979  391.6  525.6 1020.9 2252.7  800.2  239.3   57.4   62.0   21.5   23.0   32.0   24.5
1980   92.9 1036.0  812.0 1644.8  890.7  136.9   61.8   79.4   76.2   27.2   40.7   40.4
1981   28.3   40.2  194.2  447.2  120.8   36.5   51.8   77.1   61.5   69.6   38.3   43.2
1982   57.2  195.2  664.1  759.0  337.8   60.5   30.7  100.3   75.1   18.8   48.7  195.2
1983  173.0  374.9 1102.8 1707.8 1262.0  230.1   55.4   97.4  171.7  851.3   96.1  196.7
1984  256.2  171.8  322.4  260.1  107.5   22.6   25.3   68.0   80.8  268.8  107.0  602.6
1985  503.5  611.0 1863.1 1336.3  552.2  108.8   61.2  123.4   75.6  100.6   73.2   82.7
1986   50.5  329.9  759.4  538.3   82.0   39.3   54.4   47.5   48.8   76.9  368.0  227.4
1987   96.8  232.2  741.5 1341.7  411.7   69.9   39.7   76.4   39.4   39.9   97.4   37.0
1988   35.1  331.1  457.2  701.1  328.1   60.1   54.6  311.3  366.2   60.9   51.0   47.3
1989   71.3   96.9  389.8  126.3   42.7   21.6   14.1   48.7   29.5   33.1   32.2   35.4
1990   45.8   49.9  108.4   84.1   44.0   23.8   49.8   60.7   49.8   61.7   59.2  201.1
1991  308.5  286.0 1004.2 1432.8  394.0   75.8   50.5   82.2  131.3   36.9   56.7  130.3
1992  135.2  400.3  864.7 1120.7  406.4  226.6   57.8  202.7   79.7   46.2   52.8  240.0
1993 1570.8  984.8 1577.0 1926.7  687.2  157.3   62.2   61.7   61.0   45.9   49.1   50.1
1994   41.5   57.7  458.3  242.7   79.1   27.3   17.2   40.9  182.6   50.7  505.3  346.1
1995  249.0  986.1 1164.9  429.3  227.9   69.0   30.1   54.9   54.2   30.4   33.1   23.8
1996   23.0   39.5   30.1   32.0   22.5   25.2   44.6   66.8   85.8   58.5  101.0   79.2
1997  108.1  194.7  677.3  342.1  109.5   34.7   29.8   39.7   42.7   32.1   36.3   37.7
1998   54.7  124.5  802.0 1032.1  465.5   66.5   50.6   38.2   31.2   40.0   37.1   43.0
1999   38.6   39.3   31.2   91.1   33.8   30.9   67.3  509.0  120.3   41.3   38.2   40.4
2000   40.1   35.2   44.9   43.5   31.2   34.9   34.2   44.4   27.5  219.0  332.3  100.6
2001   52.6  115.6  426.8  658.7  152.7   32.0   33.4   69.5   35.3   29.7   32.3   38.3
2002   36.2   35.1   35.2   27.0   23.1   21.3   50.8   52.6   74.4   28.6   47.4   40.3
2003   61.3  166.0  629.8  413.9  102.5   31.1   29.2   44.4  121.1   30.4   67.4   41.0
2004   42.5   60.7  564.9  375.6   65.6   25.0   37.7   30.7   29.7   30.0   47.2  127.6
2005  358.6 1124.4  591.4  766.0  229.9   50.9   29.3   53.0   38.9   30.3   34.0   32.7
2006   30.9   30.4   41.3   53.1   24.6   24.9   44.5  599.1  149.7   79.6   43.5   36.4
2007   41.0   95.2  321.3  145.9   53.8   32.4   32.7  203.4   70.9   54.2   48.1  152.8
2008  393.6  600.7  991.5  532.0  156.2   50.5   67.8  138.4  296.8   97.1   39.7   46.1
2009  169.8  235.3  697.6  256.7  103.5   42.3   36.5   30.6   34.4   32.6   35.7   38.0
2010  128.3  164.4  661.3 1280.2  390.9   52.6   63.8  129.6   44.9   29.3   29.0   36.0
2011   35.8   35.4   63.9   45.2   25.3   26.5   64.9  163.0   96.0   39.7   27.8   36.3
2012   64.1  108.8  335.0  153.5   33.6   25.2   33.1   63.2   52.7   23.7   27.9   31.5
2013   86.1  153.4  481.0  174.5   48.6   25.7  203.1  193.5  578.7   88.5   55.3   67.8
2014   42.6   44.0  115.3   41.8   26.5   23.6   47.0  194.9  136.4  131.5   49.1   66.0
2015   99.4  327.8  203.0   72.3   43.1   28.1  178.9  145.1  168.8  149.3  374.5  126.5
2016   88.4  557.6  281.0   85.1   41.8   31.4   32.9   44.5   26.2   36.6   48.3  328.5
2017  527.2  934.2  684.3  205.6   63.3   27.4   66.8  188.7   30.4   31.4   22.3   24.4
2018   26.9   32.5   32.9   23.5   24.7   19.5   29.9   42.5   43.9   61.1   33.4   29.0
2019   75.5  525.9 1537.6  611.8  154.0   46.4   28.4   41.0   35.9   31.6   40.4  217.2
2020  152.1  393.1 1191.2  383.4   78.7   29.1   33.9   29.9   24.1   25.3              
>
```

However, in the code environment appears that the time series data (object ts) goes from 1953 to **2021**, instead of to 2020.

```
> str(ts_MonthlyMean[[1]])
 Time-Series [1:809] from 1953 to 2021: 25.1 32.2 26.2 11.6 13.6 ...
```

Any reason why this is happening and how can I solve it?

At the same time I am having problems applying the Seasonal Sen Slope to the data getting the following error:

```
> sea.sens.slope(ts_MonthlyMean[[1]])
Error in d[, i] <- .d(dat) : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Comment: why are you using lapply? in your code you have no need for that

Comment: I am using it for converting to ts objects all the data frames in the list called df_MonthyMean

Comment: a list called `df_...` maybe misleading for your teammates. I'd suggest you to call it `l_...`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `sea.sens.slop` works only with full periods.

This works as expected:

```
trend::sea.sens.slope(window(ts_MonthlyMean[[1]], end = c(2020,5)))
#> [1] 0.01801948
```

Your data is composed by 68 years and 5 months. You can use `sea.sens.slope` only on the 68 years. That's why I took a `window` of data.

---

The reason why you see 2021 in:

```
str(ts_MonthlyMean[[1]])
#> Time-Series [1:809] from 1953 to 2021: 25.1 32.2 26.2 11.6 13.6 ...
```

it's just because the `start` and `end` point are rounded by default in `str`:

```
tsp(ts_MonthlyMean[[1]])
#> [1] 1953.417 2020.750   12.000

oo <- options(digits = 3) # change options the same way str does

tsp(ts_MonthlyMean[[1]])
#> [1] 1953 2021   12

options(oo) # reset options
```

If you want to see it not rounded:

```
str(ts_MonthlyMean[[1]])
#> Time-Series [1:809] from 1953 to 2021: 25.1 32.2 26.2 11.6 13.6 ...


# change str options
stro <- getOption("str")
stro$digits.d <- 7
oo <- options(str = stro)


str(ts_MonthlyMean[[1]])
#> Time-Series [1:809] from 1953.417 to 2020.75: 25.1 32.2 26.2 11.6 13.6 22.7 20 26.5 38.6 322.6 ...

options(oo) # reset options
```